# What is the idea to sum this series of powers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm given the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n^2+n+1)x^{n-1}$$
which is easy to see converges iff $|x|<1$. What I'm missing is the idea behind the computation of the sum. I tried considering the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}nx^{n-1}$$
Calling $L_N$ the partial sum up to index $N$, I saw it holds:
$$xL_N-L_N=-(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{N-1})+Nx^N$$
from which: $L=\lim_N L_N=\frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}}$
up to mistakes. I was hoping this process could help me to find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n^2x^{n-1}$. I noticed there's a recursive pattern which somehow allows me to find the previous $L_N$ into the partial sum of the latter series, but I wasn't able to write it properly.

Is this even the best approach to find the general sum?

Comment: Try differentiating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}$ a few times, term-by-term, and see what you can do with the results.

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $-\frac{x^2-2 x+3}{(x-1)^3}$

Comment: you can also consider that $n^2+n+1=(n+1)n+1$.  That would give $$(n^2+n+1)x^{n-1}=(n+1)nx^{n-1}+x^{n-1}$$  THen you can reindex the one sum and use the rules of differentiation for the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small trick for this kind of summation
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n^2+n+1)x^{n-1}$$
$$n^2=n(n-1)+n\implies n^2+n+1=n(n-1)+2n+1$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n^2+n+1)x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n(n-1)x^{n-1}+2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^{n-1}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n^2+n+1)x^{n-1}=x\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n(n-1)x^{n-2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}nx^{n-1}+\frac 1x\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^{n}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n^2+n+1)x^{n-1}=x\Bigg[\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^n\Bigg]''+2\Bigg[\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^n\Bigg]'+\frac 1x\Bigg[\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^n\Bigg]$$

Answer (score 7):

Break it into terms:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^2 x^{n-1} = \frac{-x-1}{(x-1)^3}$$

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$$

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1} = \frac{-1}{x-1}$$

and then sum them.

Answer (score 1):

As a comment. It's a general method and your series can be obtained as
$$
\big((xD_x)^2+(xD_x)+1\big)f(x)
$$
where $f(x)$ is the geometric serie and $D_x$ is the derivative wrt $x$